# Pass Python object as json to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, json

I'm using Python/Flask and I've troubles converting my python object in a valid json object.

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
    sites = Site.query.filter(Site.id==2).all()

    site_list = []
    for site in sites:
        site_element = {}
        site_element['long'] = site.longitude
        site_element['lat'] = site.latitude
        site_element['id'] = site.id
        site_element['name'] = 'test'
        site_list.append(site_element)

    site_json = json.dumps(site_list, separators=(',', ':'))
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', site_json=site_json)
```

I'm consuming the json in the js like this:

```
var markers = JSON.parse('{{ site_json | tojson | safe }}');
```

It results in following error:

*Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 5 of the JSON data*

What seems strange to me: If I construct the json manually, it just works fine!

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
    sites = Site.query.filter(Site.id==2).all()

    # site_list = []
    # for site in sites:
    #     site_element = {}
    #     site_element['long'] = site.longitude
    #     site_element['lat'] = site.latitude
    #     site_element['id'] = site.id
    #     site_element['name'] = 'test'
    #     site_list.append(site_element)
    # site_json = json.dumps(site_list, separators=(',', ':'))

    site_json = [{'long':36.02, 'lat':37.04, 'id':2, 'name':'test'}]

    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', site_json=site_json)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the object rather than string. With `json.dumps` you are dumping the `json` as `string`.

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
    sites = Site.query.filter(Site.id==2).all()

    site_list = []
    for site in sites:
        site_element = {}
        site_element['long'] = site.longitude
        site_element['lat'] = site.latitude
        site_element['id'] = site.id
        site_element['name'] = 'test'
        site_list.append(site_element)
    
    # site_json = json.dumps(site_list, separators=(',', ':')) <-- this is causing problem

    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', site_json=site_list)
```